# how to build libtorrent for simulator ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, libtorrent-rasterbar

hi everyone and sorry my bad English. im newbie in ios develope, now im try to build libtorrent for iso, First of all, i have had use Booost and OpenSSL on this [github](https://gist.github.com/rsobik/7513324)

when read Script Shell build booost. i have visualization to build libtorrent i must build for iphone and iphonesimulator. Next i have using lipo to merge two lib together. but when using ./configure in libtorrent to build with option, im can'nt  find the option toolset=darwin, architecture=arm and target-os in ./configure of libtorrent. 
Any one can tell me ,what option and argruments that Im can set for libtorrent configure